# Upload multiple images in one request

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to upload more than one image in single service request. How can I do that. As of now I am able to upload single image like as

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);


 NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";


   NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

// file
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\”%@\”\r\n”,@“imagename”]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Now I want to upload two images to server how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is here. It's tested and I am using this below methods to upload multiple image along with other parameters.

```
- (void)uploadMultipleImageInSingleRequest
{

    NSString *returnString;
    NSDictionary *aParametersDic; // It's contains other parameters.
    NSDictionary *aImageDic; // It's contains multiple image data as value and a image name as key
    NSString *urlString; // an url where the request to be posted
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] ;

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *postData = [self getHTTPBodyParamsFromDictionary:aParametersDic boundary:boundary];
    [postbody appendData:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [aImageDic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if(obj != nil)
        {
            [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"PostedImage\"; filetype=\"image/png\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:obj]];
        }
    }];

    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

.

```
-(NSString *) getHTTPBodyParamsFromDictionary: (NSDictionary *)params boundary:(NSString *)boundary
{
    NSMutableString *tempVal = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for(NSString * key in params)
    {
        [tempVal appendFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary];
        [tempVal appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n%@",key,[params objectForKey:key]];
    }
    return [tempVal description];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback.. still its working for me. My parameters are getting inserted in correctly but files are not getting uploaded.. is it correct?          aImageDic = @{
                  @“image1”:imageData1,
                  @“image2”:imageData2
                  };

Comment: Thanks Its working now. I was sending wrong file name. Thats why it was not working..

Comment: It's a very good sign of a developer to find and resolve their own bug... good job bro.. keep it up... :)

Answer (score 1):

One option use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to upload multiple images

```
//create image data
UIImage *image = ......
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

 UIImage *image2 = ......
NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.5);

//Now add to array and also create array of images data
NSArray *arrImagesData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageData,imageData2,nil];

//Create manager
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
//parameters if any
NSDictionary *parameters = .......
//Now post
[manager POST:@"your url here" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
   //add img data one by one
   for(int i=0; i<[arrImagesData count];i++) 
   {
      NSData *imageData = arrImagesData[i];
      NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name%d",i]
      [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:strName];
   }


} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. But I am not using AFNetworking For Image upload. Can we do that in regular manner? I mean using simple post body like I mentioned above

Comment: How can user add parameter  like filename, fileSize, fileCreationDate for each file in multiple file uploading ?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"------VohpleBoundary4QuqLuM1cE5lMwCy";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setValue:@"IOS Testing" forKey:@"subject"];
[parameters setValue:@"Message" forKey:@"message"];
   for (NSString *param in parameters) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [parameters objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}


NSMutableArray *multipleArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[multipleArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"]];
[multipleArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"]];
for (int i=0; i<multipleArray.count;i++ )
{
    NSData *imageData;
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([multipleArray objectAtIndex:i], 1.0);
    if (imageData)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", @"uploaded_file[]"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    else
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASEURL]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                           if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
                               NSLog(@"success");
                           }

}];
```

}

Comment: You are uploading multiple image's for single parameter  "@"uploaded_file[]" right .How to send two image's with two parameter's

Answer (score 0):

```
#define kStartTag   @"--%@\r\n"
#define kEndTag     @"\r\n"
#define kContent    @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n"
#define kBoundary   @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"

-(void)uploadImageonServers
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
        NSLog(@"image upload");

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/gmento/index.php/api/professional/addServices"];

        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",kBoundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


        // user ID parameter
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kStartTag, kBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kContent, @"professional_id"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"1232" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kEndTag] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        // Grop ID parameter
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kStartTag, kBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kContent, @"title"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"test" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kEndTag] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        // prepration_type_id parameter
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kStartTag, kBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kContent, @"price"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"test" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kEndTag] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // description parameter
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kStartTag, kBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kContent, @"description"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"test" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kEndTag] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




        NSMutableArray *arr_images=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arr_images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];
        [arr_images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];
        for (int i=0; i<arr_images.count;i++ )
        {
            NSData *image_videoData;//isImageSet?imgMyProfPict.image:@""
            image_videoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([arr_images objectAtIndex:i], 1.0);
            if (image_videoData)
            {
                // image File
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kStartTag, kBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=imageName.jpeg\r\n", @"services_image[]"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:image_videoData];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kEndTag] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }
            else
            {
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kStartTag, kBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }

        }


        for (int i=0; i<arr_images.count;i++ )
        {
            NSData *image_videoData;//isImageSet?imgMyProfPict.image:@""
            image_videoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([arr_images objectAtIndex:i], 1.0);
            if (image_videoData)
            {
                // image File
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kStartTag, kBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=imageName.jpeg\r\n", @"glimpses_image[]"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:image_videoData];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kEndTag] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }
            else
            {
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:kStartTag, kBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }

        }


        // close form
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", kBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSError *error;
        id receivedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        NSDictionary *dicResponse = (NSDictionary *)receivedData;
        if ([[dicResponse valueForKeyPath:@"status"] intValue] == 1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please explain your code so it's easy for others to understand.