# Xcode - Upload photos to server issues

Tags: ios, xcode, image, file-upload, photo

I am building an app that allow users to upload photos and send to my server. But then I notice that when I try to upload multiple photos, let say 5 photos, sometimes it only uploaded 2-4 images, and sometimes uploaded 5 images. The uploading process seems not so consistent, which I think has much to do with the network. 
Here are the codes for the uploading:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
dict = [returnString JSONValue];
[responseStr addObject:[[dict objectForKey:@"Image"]objectForKey:@"Name"]];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
ImageIndex = ImageIndex+1;
[self imageUplaodAndProductUploadFunction:ImageIndex];
}
```

Then I came up an idea to work around:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
dict = [returnString JSONValue];
if([responseStr containsObject:[[dict objectForKey:@"Image"]objectForKey:@"Name"]])
{
    NSLog(@"It present");
    itcontains =YES;
}
else
{
    itcontains = NO;
    NSLog(@"Not contain");
    [responseStr addObject:[[dict objectForKey:@"Image"]objectForKey:@"Name"]];
}

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
if(itcontains == NO)
{
   ImageIndex = ImageIndex+1;
}
[self imageUplaodAndProductUploadFunction:ImageIndex];
}
```

Now, it will upload 5 photos correctly, but then a weird situation happens:
Let say I have 5 images, Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4 and Image 5.
The 5 photos upload successfully, but the image might be duplicated:
Case 1: Image1, Image2, Image2, Image4, Image4
Case 2: Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4, Image4

The duplicate can be any of the 5 images.

Can anyone help out? Thanks

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28737846/3901620

Comment: I'm assuming (a) you're running these requests concurrently; and (b) you have the same instance acting as the delegate for all of these concurrent requests; and (c) you're referencing ivars where the various concurrent requests could conceivably step on top of each other. On top of that, you're using the deprecated `NSURLConnection`. If you use `NSURLSession` with completion block, a lot of these issues would solve themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the advice.
Yes, I took a look into NSURLSession, and modify the code. 
Basically, I think the previous issues are now solve, I can now successfully upload 5 photos without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try NSURLSessionUploadTask

// Background upload only works with files

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", IMAGE_NAME_TO_BE_SAVED, @".png"];
NSString *signatureFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",  NSTemporaryDirectory(), fileName];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:signatureFile atomically:YES];

while (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:signatureFile]) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.5];
}

NSURLSession *session = [self backgroundSession];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uploadUrl]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:signatureFile]];

[uploadTask resume];
```