# How to POST Multiple images on the server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-uploading

I am trying to POST multiple images to the server but only one image is going to the server. I am trying to save multiple images. My code is below plz tell me where I am wrong. I have seen this example of posting multiple images.

> [Upload multiple images in one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736606/upload-multiple-images-in-one-request)

Thanks

```
NSData *imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo1, 0.8);
    NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo2, 0.8);
    NSData *imageData3 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo3, 0.8);
    NSData *imageData4 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.8);
    NSData *imageData5 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.8);

    NSString *returnString;
    NSDictionary *aParametersDic= @{@"input_100":userIDStr,@"input_1":regstrationNumberStr,@"input_88":regsDateStr,@"input_2":nameofHealthSeekerString,@"input_83":ageString1,@"input_84":weightStr,@"input_85":heightStr,@"input_3":motherNameStr,@"input_4":addressStr,@"input_5":phonenumberStr,@"input_95":alternativeNumberStr,@"input_6":emailStr,@"input_7":whatsAppStr,@"input_96":idProofStr1,@"input_8":professionStr1,@"input_9":maritialStatusStr,@"input_11":presentHistoryStr,@"input_12":pastHistoryStr,@"input_13":familyHistoryStr,@"input_15":sleepStr,@"input_16":freshStatusStr,@"input_17":sleepPillsStr,@"input_20":DietStr,@"input_21":spiceStr,@"input_23":apetiteStr,@"input_25":foodChewingHabbit,@"input_27":breakfastItemStr,@"input_29":lunchItemStr,@"input_31":eveningItemStr,@"input_33":dinnerItemStr,@"input_94":mentalStatus,@"input_36":relationStr,@"input_38":constipationStr,@"input_39":urinaryStr,@"input_41":habitStr,@"input_45":tasteOfMouthStr,@"input_47":sexualStr,@"input_49":fatiqueStr,@"input_51":regularExerciseStr,@"input_53":workingHoursStr,@"input_55":favDishStr,@"input_57":otherDetailsStr,@"input_59":femalStatsStr,@"input_60":progressReportStr,@"input_77":referredByStr,@"input_75_1":hearAboutStr,@"input_78":willingStr,@"input_87":_mentorNameTextField.text,@"input_90":_phonenumberTextField.text,@"input_91":_addressTextField.text};
    // It's contains other parameters.
    NSDictionary *aImageDic = @{@"input_93":imageData1,@"input_98":imageData2,@"input_92":imageData3,@"input_82":imageData4,@"input_97":imageData5 }; // It's contains multiple image data as value and a image name as key
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://nse/apis/custom/?api=1&page=user_patient_form"]; // an url where the request to be posted
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] ;

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831e45466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *postData = [self getHTTPBodyParamsFromDictionary:aParametersDic boundary:boundary];
    [postbody appendData:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [aImageDic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if(obj != nil)
        {
            [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"PostedImage\"; filetype=\"image/png\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:obj]];
        }
    }];

    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if([[jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"]boolValue])
        {
            NSLog(@"data saved successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in saving the data");
        }
    });
```

When PHP response is
Printing description of returnString:

```
Array
(
    [PostedImage] => Array
        (
            [name] => input_82
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpIfld44
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 225219
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
 [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
 [request setTimeoutInterval:60];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  NSString *boundary = @"------VohpleBoundary4QuqLuM1cE5lMwCy";
 NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
 [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
 NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [parameters setValue:@"IOS Testing" forKey:@"subject"];
 [parameters setValue:@"Message" forKey:@"message"];
 for (NSString *param in parameters) {
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [parameters objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }

  NSMutableArray *multipleArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [multipleArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"]];
 [multipleArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"]];
  for (int i=0; i<multipleArray.count;i++ )
 {
 NSData *imageData;
 imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([multipleArray objectAtIndex:i], 1.0);
 if (imageData)
 {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", @"uploaded_file[]"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   }
   else
  {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }
 }

 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [request setHTTPBody:body];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASEURL]];
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                       NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = 
   (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                       if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
                           NSLog(@"success");
                       }

 }];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can use this code. It's tested and I am using this methods to upload multiple images along with other parameters.

```
    if([arrImage count])
{
    for (int y = 0; y < [arrImage count]; y++)
    {
        //-- Convert string into URL
        NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:UPLOADDATA_URL]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = @"14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        //-- Append data into posr url using following method
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


        //Project ID
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"project_id"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",projectId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        //Date
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"date"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        //User ID
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"user_id"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        //Comment
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"comment"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",projectNoteTextView.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        //Task ID
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"task_assign_id"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",task_Id] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        image_name =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",@"image",y];
        NSLog(@"IMAGE NAME:%@", image_name);

        UIImage*  imageFile = [arrImage objectAtIndex:y];

        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(500.0f, 500.0f);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
        [imageFile drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        //  NSData *dataImg = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage)]; //compressed Imge
        //  NSData *dataImg = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([arrImage objectAtIndex:y])];

        NSLog(@"Images, send to server:%@", dataImg);
        NSLog(@"added %i", y+1);

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"site_image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",image_name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataImg]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        //-- Sending data into server through URL
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        //-- Getting response form server
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        //-- JSON Parsing with response data
        result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Result = %@",result);
    }

    [self showAlertMessage:[result objectForKey:@"message"]];
}
```

Comment: have you checked the answer?

Comment: image_name =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",@"image",y];
        NSLog(@"IMAGE NAME:%@", image_name);UIImage*  imageFile = [arrImage objectAtIndex:y];
what to write here i am having images in form of nsdata?

Comment: you can change NSData to UiImage using this:
NSData *data = yourImageData;
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];